# iOS equivalent of the MainActivity in Android

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvm-light

I’m working on an Xamarin.iOS application and I would like to know whether there is an equivalent of Android’s “MainActivity” in iOS.

The situation: I’m using Xamarin and the MVVM-Pattern to share business logic across multiple platforms (iOS, Android, WPF). The business logic provides a “MainViewModel”, which contains essential code. Therefore, I can’t ignore the “MainViewModel”.

In general, this works perfectly for all platforms except iOS, because I don’t know how to use the MainViewModel in iOS. In Android it is possible to connect the “MainViewModel” with the “MainActivity” – Is there any iOS equivalent of the "MainActivity"? Or is there another solution?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: A `UIViewController` subclass (the `ViewController` class in a template-created `Xamarin.iOS` app) would be the most direct *equivalent* of an `Activity` subclass (the `MainActivity` class in a template-created `Xamarin.Android` app).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am aware, that a ViewController and an Activity are equivalent in certain manner. Do you also know, how to implement this with the MVVM-Pattern.

Comment: There are lots of MVVMLight and Xamarin.iOS examples floating around, you might want to start with them: http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/getting-started-with-xamarin-mvvm-light/  http://danielhindrikes.se/xamarin/mvvmlight-and-xamarin_ios/ , http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/xamarin-ios-table-views-and-mvvm-light/ etc.....

Comment: Thanks for your tips. By now I know, that I can use the AppDelegate as "MainActivity"-equivalent.

Comment: An `AppDelegate` equivalent on Android would be the `Application` subclass